# Uncaught ReferenceError: Function is not defined using external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of rows with contact details and a call button in every row, which when clicked should call the customer.

I am using onclick on call the function defined in external js file (I know not the best practice and potentially due to outside scope, but I am passing the phone number as well)

I am getting error Uncaught Referenceerror: function is not defined

https://jsfiddle.net/e1z25y3w/3/

```
<table>
<th>
  <td>#</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>City</td>
  <td>Phone Number</td>
  <td>Call</td>
</th>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Melbourne</td>
  <td>+61123456789</td>
  <td><a role="button" onclick="callPhone('+61123456789')">Call</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Tanya</td>
  <td>Sydney</td>
  <td>+61987654321</td>
  <td><a role="button" onclick="callPhone('+61987654321')">Call</a></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Jquery 3.4.1 included at the bottom of the page
javascript file also included after jquery

```
$(function () {
  //const phoneNumberInput = document.getElementById("phone-number");

function callPhone(phonenumber) {
alert(here);
      log("calling phone number " + phonenumber.value);
      //e.preventDefault();
      phoneNumberInput = phonenumber;
      makeOutgoingCall();
  }
});
```

What is the best way to execute this?

Comment: Your `callPhone` is in the *scope* of the doc.ready.  Don't put functions in doc.ready, put DOM manipulation in doc.ready.

Comment: @freedomn-m  Since there are more than one row, I am trying to get the element array using document.getElementsByClassName("button-call");

Then I need to find which row was clicked and then get the phone number for that row as well. Let me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because the "callPhone" function isn't in the global scope, so when you to try call it, will give "callPhone is not defined".

1- first solution is to write it on the global scope.

```
function callPhone(phonenumber) {
  console.log('running')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/rakeopg2/9

2- The second solution is to store it in a global variable.

```
let referanceStore = null
$(function () {
//const phoneNumberInput = document.getElementById("phone-number");

function callPhone(phonenumber) {
  // any code here...
  console.log('running')
}
referanceStore = callPhone

});
```

and use referancecStore to call your function
ex:

```
referanceStore('+61987654321')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/z391euhm/7

3- Third solution is to use the javascript click event and dataset instead.

https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/z391euhm/22/

Comment: So this html calls a javascript function that is defined in an external javascript file.

I have many other functions in the external js file that other html pages will also call, so I can't bring all the functions to all file. Did you get a chance to look at jsfiddle file?

Comment: Yes, The issue of your code is the callPhone function is wrapped inside jquery $(function() {}), which doesn't make it in the global scope.

https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/rakeopg2/9/

Comment: The second solution is store the function to a variable in the global scope, so you can call it. https://jsfiddle.net/mena234/z391euhm/7/

Comment: this is good, but when I take the callPhone function outside the $(function(){ }); , it works, but then I am not able to call other functions define inside. So, should I take all functions outside?

Comment: your second jsfiddle made some progress, however, I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: Yes, any code which you need to call it from HTML, you need to take it to outside the $function() {})

Comment: The second jsfiddle works fine in my side. https://recordit.co/7t32dbIA6R

Comment: You really should avoid the first and second solution. Polluting the global namespace and using inline event handlers are really bad to maintain and can lead to various problems. @MoC

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use an inline event handler (`onclick="callPhone('+61123456789')"`)

Your inline event handler can't find the `function callPhone(phonenumber)` because it is defined within the anonymous callback function passed to your `$( ... )` so it is only visible in it.

So the first idea of how to solve it would be to make the `callPhone` globally visible. This however is a bad idea as it pollutes the global namespace.

You instead should get rid of your inline event handlers and attach the event handler within the scope where `callPhone` is defined, using e.g. event delegation and data attributes:

```js
$(function() {
  function callPhone(phonenumber) {
    console.log("calling phone number " + phonenumber);
  }
  
  // use event delegation to listen a click on elements with the  data-action attribute beeing callPhone
  $(document).on('click', '[data-action="callPhone"]', function(evt) {
    // get the contents of the data attribute phone-number
    // and pass it to the callPhone function
    callPhone($(evt.target).data().phoneNumber)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td>Call</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Melbourne</td>
    <td>+61123456789</td>
    <td><a role="button" data-phone-number="+61123456789" data-action="callPhone">Call</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Tanya</td>
    <td>Sydney</td>
    <td>+61987654321</td>
    <td><a role="button" data-phone-number="+61987654321" data-action="callPhone">Call</a></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```